# Azure Academic Search API: GraphSearch

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Making the following API call on the Graphsearch api:

```
POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/graph/search?mode=json HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{
  "path": "/paper/AuthorIDs/author",
  "paper": {
    "type": "Paper",
    "NormalizedTitle": "graph engine",
    "select": [
      "OriginalTitle"
    ]
  },
  "author": {
    "return": {
      "type": "Author",
      "Name": "bin shao"
    }
  }
}
```

returns an Internal Server Error 500:

```
Pragma: no-cache
apim-request-id: ab90bbda-b1e7-4f55-b939-770ef086579b
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Tue, 06 Jun 2017 16:31:17 GMT
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 108
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
{
  "Error": {
    "Message": "Something went wrong, if the error continue please contact us",
    "Code": "InternalError"
  }
}
```

I am just using the Open API testing console to test the API.

Comment: Weird, I get the same error.

Comment: FYI I posted the issue here: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/555931-academic-knowledge/suggestions/19516336-the-examples-in-the-docs-give-500-internal-server

Comment: Thanks @MariaInesParnisari

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been resolved on their end. With the body in your question, I get the following answer:

```
{
    "Results": [
        [
            {
                "CellID": 2171539317,
                "OriginalTitle": "A distributed graph engine for web scale RDF data"
            },
            {
                "CellID": 2093502026
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "CellID": 73304046,
                "OriginalTitle": "The Trinity Graph Engine"
            },
            {
                "CellID": 2093502026
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```